# changing date format in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to change date format from `20211018` to `202110180000`. of a column of a spark data frame.

I have the following code to create new `dt` column out of existing `data_dt`

```
func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'), DateType())
    
result_df = result_df.withColumn('dt', func(col('data_dt')))
result_df = result_df.select('data_dt', 
                   from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('data_dt', '%Y%m%d0000')).alias('dt'))
```

which throws a error:

> 'ValueError: time data '20211018' does not match format '%Y%m%d0000''

I tried the correct format of date `"%Y%m%d%H%M"`. It throws other error. Please let me know how to fix this. I want defaulted `0000` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for UDF. Simply cast the string into date type using `to_date` then apply `date_format` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("20211018",)], ["data_dt"])

result_df = df.withColumn(
    "dt",
    F.date_format(F.to_date("data_dt", "yyyyMMdd"), "yyyyMMddHHmm")
)

result_df.show()
#+--------+------------+
#| data_dt|          dt|
#+--------+------------+
#|20211018|202110180000|
#+--------+------------+
```

See Spark docs for [Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)